# Is there a special name given if a number is on the edge of an interval?

Tags: interval-arithmetic

For instance, if I have the interval $[0,1]$, is it proper to say that $0$ is on the lower bound of the interval?

I'm looking for the most elegant way to express this.

Comment: I think the best way to say it is $0$ is the infimum of $[0,1]$, i.e., $$0=\inf[0,1]$$Lower bound isn't wrong, but $0$ is more special than just being a lower bound.

Comment: You could also call $0$ the left endpoint of the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: "Lower boundary" could also work

Comment: It could be called a [boundary point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)), even in more general circumstances

Comment: I would prefer some term including the word "boundary" or "endpoint", as opposed to just $\inf$ or $\sup$ -- after all, $0=\inf(0,1)$ too, but $0$ is not in $(0,1)$. It might be just me, but the words boundary or endpoint tacitly imply that $0$ is actually in the interval.

Comment: @DonThousand I think "minimum" is better than "infimum" there.

Comment: Lower end and upper end is better. Because $0.5$ is also lower bound. But $0$ is the only lower end.

Comment: @peter.petrov Huh? $0.5$ is **not** a lower bound of $[0,1]$. $-0.5$ would be, though.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I meant more like $-0.5$ sorry. I meant any number smaller than the lower end is lower bound.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Fantastic.

Comment: It appears there may not be consensus on the best wording.

Comment: @DanielScott Welcome to the wonderful world of mathematical terminology. :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's mostly in English, it seems (at least based on my limited experience reading/watching some math in English). There are sometimes two terms for the same thing in English. Or one author uses this term, another one uses that term. This was very surprising to me.

Comment: @peter.petrov Two? Hah. In my subfield, "recursively enumerable," "computably enumerable," "semidecidable," and "recognizable" all mean the same thing. And I'm probably forgetting a few others.

Answer (score 3):

One relevant term here is "**boundary point**." Roughly speaking, $x$ is a boundary point of $Y$ (I'm working in $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity) iff there are points outside of $Y$ "arbitrarily close" to $x$: for all $\epsilon>0$, there is some $z$ such that $z\not\in Y$ but $\vert x-z\vert<\epsilon$. For example, $x=0$ is a boundary point of $Y=[0,1]$ since given $\epsilon>0$ the point $-{\epsilon\over 2}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$ but is not in $Y$.

*(There is a [more general notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)#Common_definitions) of "boundary point," but it's more technical.)*

However, this is a somewhat slippery notion. For example, **every** real number is a boundary point of $\mathbb{Q}$, since there are irrationals arbitrarily close to every real number. Similarly, $0$ is also a boundary point of $(0,1)$ even though $0\not\in (0,1)$. For this reason, terms like "**endpoint**" may be preferred.

(Why not "minimum" or "maximum?" Well, those terms are great for individual intervals, but consider something a bit more complicated like $A=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$. The point $1$ is an endpoint of $A$, but is neither the minimum nor maximum of $A$.)

Answer (score 0):

If the word is about a single/individual interval (on the real line),
I would just use the terms **lower end** and **upper end** to keep things simple.

I am pretty sure I've seen these being used.

So for $[0,1]$ the number zero is the lower end,
and the number one is the upper end of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)$ denote the set $\{\alpha\in\Bbb{R}\mid x<\alpha<y\}$ (open interval)

Let $(x,y]$ denote the set $\{\alpha\in\Bbb{R}\mid x<\alpha\le y\}$ (half open)

Let $[x,y)$ denote the set $\{\alpha\in\Bbb{R}\mid x\le\alpha< y\}$ (half open)

Let $[x,y]$ denote the set $\{\alpha\in\Bbb{R}\mid x\le \alpha\le y\}$ (closed)

---

There are a few different terms used to refer to different extreme points along subsets of the real line:

A *lower bound* of an interval $I$ is any element $u$ such that for any $e\in\Bbb{R}$, if $e<u$ then $e\notin I$. For example, $-14$ is *a* lower bound of $(0,1)$. Note that a lower bound does not need to be close to the "lower end" of the interval.

An *upper bound* of an interval $I$ is any element $u$ such that for any $e\in\Bbb{R}$, if $e>u$ then $e\notin I$. For example, $96$ is *an* upper bound of $(0,1)$. Note that an upper bound does not need to be close to the "upper end" of the interval.

The *minimum* of an interval is its least element - i.e. $x$ is the minimum of $[x,y)$ and $[x,y]$. Note that sets which are open on the left do not have a minimum.

The *infimum* of an interval (open or closed) is its *greatest lower bound* - i.e. the infimum of all of the above intervals is $x$. Note that every minimum is an infimum, but the converse need not hold.

The *maximum* of an interval its greatest element - i.e. $y$ is the maximum of $(x,y]$ and $[x,y]$. Not that intervals which are open on the right do not have a maximum.

The *supremum* of an interval (open or closed) is its *least upper bound* - i.e. the supremum of all of the above intervals is $y$. Note that every maximum is an supremum, but the converse need not hold.

---

In the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb{R}$, every *limit point* of an interval is either an *infimum* or *supremum*. It should be noted, however, that limit points in general (even when working in the reals) do not need to behave this way. For a full discussion of limit points, I would suggest looking through any suitably thorough undergraduate textbook on topology.